# [Pyinstaller][Django] Overwrite file in third-party libraries only for exe

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller

I need to overwrite third-party library to working with pyinstaller.
I need this only for compile my django project to working as exe on windows so i don't wanna overwite all packages in my project, just change this one file for compilation purpose.

In coreschema witch use one of the package required for django i need to change (path  _MEIPASS witch is use for pyinstaller) :

```
loader = jinja2.PackageLoader('coreschema', 'templates')
```

to

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
  # we are running in a bundle
  bundle_dir = sys._MEIPASS
  loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(bundle_dir)
else:
  loader = jinja2.PackageLoader('coreschema', 'templates')

env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
```

How to do this ?

Comment: you may have to change it directly in third-party library, next create your exe, and later eventually put back original code in this library.

Comment: @furas unfortunately i need connect create of this .exe to pipeline. So i can't do that in manually way. 
The best way it was add symlink to changed files but don't have idea how to do this. 
First way i  try to use: --add-data but this not working with .py files.